# Python : Convert a string in such a way that all even numbered letters are in upper case and odd are in lower case

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to convert a string in an accepting function and return a resulting string in which all the even numbered letters are in uppercase and odd ones are in lower case. For example, `"europe"` would become `"eUrOpE"`. My following code is throwing syntax error at line 3. What's wrong?

```
       def myfunc(mystring):
             for i, c in enumerate(mystring):
                  if i%2 = 0:
                        c = c.upper()
                  else:
                        c = c.lower()
                 newstring = c + c
             return newstring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `i%2 == 0` - you're assigning with `=`, not comparing with `==`.

Additionally, if that condition is true, you want `c` to be `c.lower()`, and vice versa - right now your code will return "EuRoPe" since arrays are zero-indexed in python.

Finally, `newstring` will only hold two copies of the last letter you give it as it's written right now, since each time you finish a for loop, you're overwriting its previous value with `c+c`. Try this instead:

```py
def myfunc(mystring):
  newstring = ""
  for i, c in enumerate(mystring):
      if i%2 == 0:
            c = c.lower()
      else:
            c = c.upper()
      newstring = newstring + c
  return newstring

print(myfunc('hello'))
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/MushyBlindArrays)

Answer (score 3):

Use the comparison operator (`==`), not the assignment operator (`=`):

```
if i%2 == 0:
```

You can make this easier though by just using the implicit falsehood of 0:

```
if not i%2:
```

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic way of writing this would be:

```
def modify_s(s):
    new_s = ""
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        new_c = c.upper() if i % 2 else c.lower()
        new_s += new_c
    return new_s
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use comprehension and `join` like,

```
>>> x = 'foobar'
>>> ''.join(c.lower() if idx % 2 == 0 else c.upper() for idx, c in enumerate(x))
'fOoBaR'
>>> def myfunc(string):
...   return ''.join(c.lower() if idx % 2 == 0 else c.upper() for idx, c in enumerate(string))
... 
>>> myfunc('foobar')
'fOoBaR'
>>>
```

Also, there's a fun way of doing things too :) [Don't do this]

```
>>> x
'foobar'
>>> # we can make use of slice awesomeness of iterables :)
>>> x[::2] # get the even parts
'foa'
>>> x[1::2] # get the odd parts
'obr'
>>> ''.join(a+b for a,b in zip(x[::2].lower(), x[1::2].upper()))
'fOoBaR'
```